# Come on Irene! Hurricane recording

Tags: hurricane, rain, wind

So, while the rest of the East Coast is freaking out, I plan on going out and recording as much chaos and destruction as my SD cards can hold. I was wondering if any others will be doing the same, and if any of you have tips for recording in bad weather. Really bad weather.

Comment: LOL! Great minds think alike @Miles! You beat me to it by 3 minutes!

Comment: @Steve Yeah, but I cheated. Yours is twenty times longer than mine. :D

Comment: I'm thinking of doing it as well. Will just have to sneak out when the wife ain't looking. ;)

Comment: Jealous! Would love to hear the recordings.

Comment: I can't believe how well the East Coast is set up for rain and storms. If this happened in L.A. I could get the wind, storm, rain FX as well as millions of people panicking and screaming and not knowing what to do. I miss the seasons Fall, Winter, and Spring. L.A. only has Summer. :-(

Comment: The hurricane is now expected to weaken to a tropical storm by the time it reaches my area, so that's a good thing for everybody. I'll still be able to get some good storm/rain/wind/debris sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Just a safety thing - we have lots of hurricanes here in the south.  If you are in a wooded area, I would record blind,  your headphones removed the ability to accurately localize something and that could make the difference in having something hit you or not.  Its really scary to hear a tree break and go oooo that sounded awesome and then it falls 3 feet from you....true story.

On a side note usually it is lots of rain and wind, not too much thunder.  So focus on the objects moving and rustling, back of mic into the wind or using a wall to block the wind on your mic but focus on an object in the wind.  If the eye of the storm passes over you, it will be intense, then dead calm, then right back to intense.  Really cool transitions/ storm swelling opportunities.  The last few hurricanes here, that time was spent repairing holes in the roof and tree removal from said roof, so I could not take the time to record it.

I have always wanted to bury/attach a contact mic onto a tree and record the wood stressing in the strong winds, but have not had the chance.

Not sure how strong the storm will be when it hits, but cat 3's and 4's are pretty intense.  Alot of that feeling comes from so much happening all around you at once, multiple perspectives/ surround recordings would really bring that out.

Best of luck, hope to hear them, stay safe and be aware of whats happening around you.

Comment: @Michael Gilbert, excellent advise! Love the contact mic in a tree suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I hate to be that guy, but...

As exciting as it definitely will be for all of you who'll be out recording the hurrcane, you'll also be greatly profiting by the gross misfortune of potentially thousands of people.  The value of the damage will probably come in at well-over a large number of millions of dollars.

It is also more than likely that someone amidst the chaos will lose their life.

Perhaps for karma's sake it might be best not to rapturously exclaim at, and rejoice in, the destruction of other people's lives and livelihoods?

Comment: Thank you for that wisdom @harry. Events like this have many faces. Also, by going out into this stuff, I'm risking ending up on the misfortunate side. :-S

Comment: Or you could end up being in the right place at the right time to help someone in need.

Comment: Don't see how he would be profiting from the misfortune of people? It's not his fault the hurricane is heading their way...bit far fetched, I don't think it was his intention to disrespect the power and destruction of the hurricane or the damage it will cause. Whether they're recording or not they can't help someone lose their life.

Get out there and record it just be careful! Maybe contact some stormchasers and ask if you can go with them as atleast they will have experience in it.

Comment:  @Jay @edmatthews82 - Indeed, given the opportunity I'd be out there myself. My problem is not with the act of recording the storm, but the mode of thought that those ^^^ exclamation points imply.

Comment: When life gives you lemons, you tear them apart for Foley.

Comment: I just realized that the reference may have been lost here. By "Come on Irene!", I was referencing Dexy's Midnight Runners' lyric "Come on Eileen!"

Comment: There's also Sam Roberts' "don't walk away Eileen."

Comment: there are so many things you could record that can be connected to some "misfortune of others"... what about gun and explosion libraries knowing that guns are meant to kill people or car sounds knowing that thousands of people die each week from car accidents? I think its an ethical issue for the recordist to decide. most I hope would use some sense not to profit (make money of fame) off an actual misfortune ( areal accident) which is different than recording the sound of howling windows or trees creaking in the wind.

Comment: @jgrzinich - I have no issue with the recording of such things. They, as much as anything else, are a part of life and are therefore worthy of recording. In fact, they SHOULD be recorded. I don't mean to tell anyone to think or do, just to maybe add a bit of perspective. For me, anything that has the power to do us such great harm deserves our respect, not reverence (or for that matter, anticipatory glee).  